# How to accomplish OCR id card in Android?

Tags: android, opencv, ocr, tesseract, firebase-mlkit

I am very new to OCR and I would like to know your opinion. I have a task where I need to fetch informations from identity card (just one country) using camera. I tried to OCR some bitmaps which contain front or back of id with Tesserac for Android, but results were very bad (both performance and accuracy)

Second attempt was to use MLKit from Firebase. Here, results are very very good (in contrast to Tesserac), especially when it comes to performance, but accuracy is still not sufficient. I am corious if it is even possible to make this task done without having trained my own model for that.

What is your thoughts and experience regarding that topic? Can you spot some directions I can go to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From which country you need to OCR ID card?

Best regards

Comment: Hi, I need it for Poland

Comment: You can use the out-of-the-shelf product as Microblink's BlinkID which already supports scanning Poland ID, for front and back side. It also has a combined recognizer which combines the data from both sides, extracts the image of the document and the face of the owner. It can also return the hi-res image of the successful frame that was processed. You can check our SDK [here](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android).

DISCLAIMER: I work for a company that created BlinkID

Best regards

Comment: @culoi thank you for your response. Unfortunatelly I cannot use any paid solution, but I saw BlinkId and I need to admit that works very well and is probably the best for ID OCR. Are you Android dev? In BlinkId, do you use only preview from camera for all devices or maybe take picture silently? 
Regards

Comment: We have a couple option, we do use camera preview but we use video stream and process every frame to boost OCR accuracy. We also have a Direct API where you can upload an image of the document or Web API/Docker component for for web browsers. After processing the image on every platform and product, you can get fullDocument Image, face image and also full res image with max available camera resolution. Regards

Answer (score 2):

to have a very good result you need to perform some image processing before applying the OCR , you need to check the official tesseract github link for more preprocessing levels 
check [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)

for training model , you almost need it for almost not clear or handwritten text